# I want to select last row when my excel get closed...Any macro code is there?

Tags: excel, vba

here is the code but which event i need to trigger ??

```
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox LastRow
```

Comment: Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select

Comment: this code is working fine ..but i want to execute this code before excel get closed

Comment: See workbook close event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose
Consider using fully qualified worksheet names.